# Mikrotik Router: How can I to setup a local wifi network in RouterOS v6.44.6 (from the scratch)?

Tags: router, wifi-configuration, setup, virtual-wifi, mikrotik

I have a Mikrotik Router: **RouterOS v6.44.6 (long-term)**. I wanted to setup a local wifi network without accessing the internet for now.

Anytime when I try to setup a wifi network, I get "Masterinterface: unknown".

**So I did some research, I tried to setup:** https://www.autoconfig.my.id/2019/05/configuring-the-master-slave-port-on-mikrotik.html

But I don't have the "Master Port tab", like it is shown in the instruction.

**I also do not have a preconfigured wifi network like here:** https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Making_a_simple_wireless_AP

**Does anyone have any idea how to setup a local wifi network in RouterOS v6.44.6 (from the scratch)?** If you have any questions, feel free to ask! I appreciate your help!

Comment: What is your router's model, and could you show a screenshot of the interfaces that you actually have?

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't have the "Master Port tab", like it is shown in the instruction.

The instructions are out of date. Recent RouterOS versions do not have this option anymore; instead they automatically configure switching for ports which belong to the same *bridge.* So you should create a bridge via `/interface bridge`, then add **all** of your LAN ports to it – you'll see them showing up with an `H` flag indicating that hardware offloading is active (i.e. the bridging is done by a switch).

Don't forget to add the Wi-Fi interface to the bridge as well. (It won't have the `H` flag listed; that's normal.)

> I also do not have a preconfigured wifi network like here:

You don't need to have "Virtual AP" interfaces. They're only needed if you want to host multiple SSIDs on the same radio, and you can add/remove them at any time (via the "+" button).

For a simple wireless network you only need to configure the actual hardware interface (the one that shows up with "Type: Wireless" – wlan1 in the picture).

(If your device is dual-band, it will have two "Wireless" interfaces and you'll need to configure both separately.)

However, if you do not have *any* interfaces with type "Wireless", then it is possible that your router simply doesn't have Wi-Fi built-in. Not all routers have Wi-Fi!